# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value CMMotionManager

Tags: swift, cmmotionmanager

Trying to implement this [raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/57368/trigonometry-game-programming-sprite-kit-version-part-1) tutiorial in swift , but unfortunately I am

```
  fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

on line

```
    let acceleration :CMAcceleration = self.motionManager!.accelerometerData.acceleration
```

Can any body please help why its occuring

please down scene file from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hlkayknnplmwbvx/GameScene.swift?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

`self.motionManager` is nil and you try to unwrap a `nil` value.Always unwrap optional values by checking for `nil` with optional binding or use optional chaining.

```
if let motionManager = self.motionManager {
   if let accelerometerData = motionManager.accelerometerData {
      let acceleration :CMAcceleration = accelerometerData.acceleration
   }
 }
 else {
   print("motion manager is nil")
 }
```

You should check your code if you have intialized `motionManager` or not.

**EDIT**

I have checked documentation

> Returns the latest sample of accelerometer data, or nil if none is
>   available.
>        */
>
> ```
> var accelerometerData: CMAccelerometerData! { get }
> ```

So you need to also check nil for `accelerometerData`.It can be `nil` and it is Implicitly wrapped optional so it will crash when data not available.

Comment: @Ali Edited answer have a look